# how to fix "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response"

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, export-to-excel

i get the following Exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" when i want to export data from database to excel file.

/****  Service ****/

```
@Component("articleExporter")
public class ArticleExporter implements FileExporter{

    @Autowired
    private IArticleService articleService;

    private static final String FILE_NAME="Liste des articles";

    @Override
    public boolean exportDataToExcel(HttpServletResponse response, String filename, String encodage) {
        if(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(filename)) {
            filename=FILE_NAME;

        }
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(encodage)) {
            encodage=ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_ENCODAGE;
        }
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ filename +".xls");
        WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        workbookSettings.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        try {
            WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream(), workbookSettings);
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(filename, 0);
            /**
             * Header of the table
             * */

            Label labelRubrique = new Label(0, 0, ApplicationConstants.RUBRIQUE);
            labelRubrique.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelRubrique.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelRubrique);

            Label labelFournisseur = new Label(1, 0, ApplicationConstants.FOURNISSEUR);
            labelFournisseur.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelFournisseur.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelFournisseur);

            Label labelcode = new Label(2, 0, ApplicationConstants.CODE);
            labelcode.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelcode.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelcode);

            Label labelReference = new Label(3, 0, ApplicationConstants.REFRENCE);
            labelReference.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelReference.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelReference);

            Label labelReferenceProtronic = new Label(4, 0, ApplicationConstants.REFERENCE_PROTRONIC);
            labelReferenceProtronic.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelReferenceProtronic.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelReferenceProtronic);

            Label labelDesignationL = new Label(5, 0, ApplicationConstants.DESIGNATION_L);
            labelDesignationL.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelDesignationL.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelDesignationL);

            Label labelDesignationC = new Label(6, 0, ApplicationConstants.DESIGNATION_C);
            labelDesignationC.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelDesignationC.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelDesignationC);

            Label labelPrixUnitaireHT = new Label(7, 0, ApplicationConstants.PRIX_UNIT_HT);
            labelPrixUnitaireHT.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelPrixUnitaireHT.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelPrixUnitaireHT);

            Label labelQuantite = new Label(8, 0, ApplicationConstants.QUANTITE);
            labelQuantite.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelQuantite.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelQuantite);

            Label labelPrixUnitaireTTC = new Label(9, 0, ApplicationConstants.PRIX_UNIT_TTC);
            labelPrixUnitaireTTC.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelPrixUnitaireTTC.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelPrixUnitaireTTC);

            Label labelTauxTVA = new Label(10, 0, ApplicationConstants.TAUX_TVA);
            labelTauxTVA.setCellFeatures(new WritableCellFeatures());
            labelTauxTVA.getCellFeatures().setComment("");
            sheet.addCell(labelTauxTVA);

            int currentRow =1;
            List<Article>  listArticles = articleService.selectAll();
            if(/*listArticles !=null &*/ !listArticles.isEmpty()) {
                /**
                 * Writing in the sheet
                 */
                for (Article article : listArticles) {

                    sheet.addCell(new Label(0,currentRow,article.getRubrique().getDesignation()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1,currentRow,article.getFournisseur().getNomFournisseur()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2,currentRow,article.getCodeArt()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(3,currentRow,article.getRefArt()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(4,currentRow,article.getRefArtPro()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(5,currentRow,article.getDesignationL()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(6,currentRow,article.getDesignationC()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(7,currentRow,article.getPrixUnitaireHT().toString()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(8,currentRow,article.getQuantite().toString()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(9,currentRow,article.getPrixUnitaireTTC().toString()));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(10,currentRow,article.getTauxTva().toString()));
                    currentRow++;
                    }
                CellView cellView= new CellView();
                cellView.setAutosize(true);
                //cellView.setSize(600);
                sheet.setColumnView(0, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(1, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(2, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(3, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(4, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(5, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(6, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(7, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(8, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(9, cellView);
                sheet.setColumnView(10, cellView);

                /**
                 * Write to excel sheet
                 */

                workbook.write();

                /**
                 * Closing the workbook
                 */

                workbook.close();

                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();

            }
            return true;

        }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             return false;

        }

    }

/* the controller */

@RequestMapping(value="/export/")
public String ExportArticles(HttpServletResponse response) {

        exporter.exportDataToExcel(response, null, null);
        return "article/article";
}
```

/*** ERRORS ***/

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: "getOutputStream()" a déjà été appelé pour cette réponse
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:582)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:227)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:108)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:179)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.article.article_jsp._jspService(article_jsp.java:406)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `workbook.write(); workbook.close();` it is already doing

```
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

So the exception is thrown, remove that lines and it will be ok.

Comment: i tried to remove that two lines but the problem persist, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error gets thrown from within Catalina (Tomcat). I assume Catalina tries to flush and close the response's outputstream itself but you have already closed it.

Does it work if you remove the `response.getOutputStream().close();` call and the `workbook.close;` call, therefore leaving the outputstream open for catalina to flush and close?

Comment: i tried also this but the exception is thrown anyway.